# Regular expression search all substrings between two keywords with linebreaks

Tags: python, regex

Lets say I have a python string `'\\[this\\] is \\[some\n text\\].'`

```
s = "\\[this\\] is \\[some\n text\\]."
```

I would like a regular expression that would return me substrings "this" and "some\n text".
I've tried

```
re.search(r'\\[(.*)\\]',s)
```

but it does not work (return None)

Answer (score 1):

You miss one backslash in the regex, and use `re.DOTALL` for the dot `.` to match the newline char

```
import re

s = "\\[this\\] is \\[some\n text\\]."
r = re.findall(r'\\\[(.*?)\\\]', s, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(r)  # ['this', 'some\n text']
```

Comment: Fast! I had `x=re.findall(r'(?s)\[([^\]]*)\\\]',s)` with links to http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html and https://riptutorial.com/regex/example/32238/why-doesn-t-dot-----match-the-newline-character----n---

Answer (score 0):

I will take the string you posted literally, but you can easily edit [the regex](https://regex101.com/r/3nKzxB/1) to match another pattern.

I think that this can do the work:

```
'\\\\\[(.*?)\\\\\]'
```

Explained:

- `\` escapes a character, so with \ you escape a backslash. Since you have to find 2 backslashes, you need 2 more of them as escape characters (4 in total)
- For the same reason as above, you need one more `\` to escape the `[` character
- `(` sets your **capturing group**
- `.` matches any character
- `*` as many times as possible, but followed by a `?` it means **as few times as possible**
- `)` closes your capturing group
- the other 5 `\` followed by `]` work as explained before (escaping the backslash/bracket sequence)

Hope I helped ;)

Comment: That would match `r"\\[this\\] is \\[some\n text\\]."` not `"\\[this\\] is \\[some\n text\\]."` ;) these are different string, not the `r` preffix

Comment: @azro yep, but the OP didn't ask that explicitly (I said that I used the literal string in fact). If you need that a match starts with `\\[` and ends with `\\]` you can use [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). The regex will look like this: `\B\\\\\[(.*?)\\\\\]\B`

Answer (score 0):

You can use use negated character class `([^][]*)` with a capture group, and match the `\` right before the closing `]` outside of the group.

```
import re
s = "\\[this\\] is \\[some\n text\\]."

print(re.findall(r"\[([^][]*)\\]", s))
```

Output

```
['this', 'some\n text']
```